# Почему в одном случае функция выведется на экран, а в другом нет?

Tags: php, функции

```html
$m = date('i');

function p($m){
 $m0 = $m % 10;


 if($m >= 5 && $m <=20 ){
  $res = 'минут';
 }
 else if($m0 == 1){
   $res = 'минута';
 }
 else if($m0 >= 2 && $m0 <= 4 ){
  $res  = 'минуты';
 }
 else{
  $res = 'минут';
 }
 return $res;
}

echo $m . p($m);
```

Вот так функция выведется на экран:

```
echo $m . p($m);
```

А так не выведется на экран:

```
echo p($m);
```

Почему?

Comment: покажите код функции

Comment: @ Anton Kucenko все

Comment: выводит только одно слово без цифр?

Comment: @ Anton Kucenko да

Comment: В обоих случаях функция возвращает значение 'минут', все работает правильно. Во втором случае нет значения переменной $m, поэтому выводится только результат работы функции, вот и вся разница.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все логично, ведь вы присваиваете переменной `$res` только определенное слово в зависимости от условия. Измените код следующим образом:

```
$m = date('i');

        function p($m){
            $m0 = $m % 10;
            $res = $m0;

            if($m >= 5 && $m <=20 ){
                $res .= 'минут';
            }
            else if($m0 == 1){
                $res .= 'минута';
            }
            else if($m0 >= 2 && $m0 <= 4 ){
                $res  .= 'минуты';
            }
            else{
                $res .= 'минут';
            }
            return $res;
        }

        echo  p($m);
```

Comment: а не сотрется  $res = $m0; потому что ВЫ сделали склейку строк вот тут  $res .= 'минут'; правильно ?

Comment: сработает только одно условие и вернет значение

Comment: а в первом if сработает там же $m, а не $m0 ?